# Debian Stretch update issue

Tags: apt, debian-stretch

I am trying to keep updated my debian stretch on my laptop.
When i run this command

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

it shows following output

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                  
E: The repository 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Here is my sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1):

As stands in the apt-secure manpage:

`Starting with version 0.6, APT contains code that does signature checking of the Release file for all repositories.`

This means that if **apt** cannot verify the signatures it wont go on. It will only update if you specify `--allow-unauthenticated` in apt like this:

`sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated update`